Display result of overall loss validation graph
Can I display the results of the overall loss validation graph from the last checkpoint? so I can see the difference between learning curve loss train and loss vall, because from the code that I run the graph only displays the last point of the checkpoint without any graph being displayed
here's the code : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FsEcBx80ldypOZaBWun49Mo1C0Fg_XLH?usp=sharing
you can fix it directly
